# unable to get log4net to use WebServiceAppender from crm 2011

Tags: log4net, dynamics-crm-2011

I have attempted to use a log4net webserviceappender from within a crm 2011 plugin (sandboxed), log4net apparently gets installed along with the plugin correctly (exception if log4net config file is malformed), but apparently the appender doesn't get called.  I can call the webservice directly from within the plugin, so that part is working, but can't figure out what might be wrong with log4net.

Does anyone know of a step by step for using log4net with crm and/or have a good idea as to why the webserviceappender doesn't get called?

Thanks

EDIT: Including log4net.config file upon request.

```
  <!-- WebService parameters. -->
  <param name="Url" value="http://my-internal-server/errorlog/ErrorHandler.asmx" />
  <param name="TimeoutSeconds" value="60" />

  <!-- Proxy parameters. -->
  <param name="UseProxy" value="false" />
  <param name="ProxyUrl" value="http://myproxy:3128" />
  <param name="ProxyBypassOnLocal" value="true" />
  <param name="ProxyUseDefaultCredentials" value="true" />
  <param name="ProxyCredentialsDomain" value="OFFICE" />
  <param name="ProxyCredentialsUserName" value="MyUser" />
  <param name="ProxyCredentialsPassword" value="MyPassword" />
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="Info" />
  <appender-ref ref="WebServiceAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Can we see the relevant web.config section?

Comment: @ckeller: I used ILMerge to join it with the plugin I was using it from.

Comment: did you deploy the config on the file system or as plugin configuration value?

Comment: @ckeller: as a file on the file system, but I'm pretty sure that I had to use a full path to make sure the file was picked up, otherwise it was crashing, so I don't think it wasn't reading the config file.  But I'll recheck.

Comment: @ckeller: on thinking about it, that sounds quite plausible, you should write it up as an answer, so I can accept it  if it turns out to be the solution.

Comment: @ckeller: on checking into it, that was exactly the problem.  I now have log4net working from within CRM 2011 (hitting a webservice).  I created a class with a static method that returned a XmlElement, and then called `XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4NetConfig.BuildXMLString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have deployed the configuration file on disk. This is not the ideal place as you have to deal with different requirements for the different modules.

To simplify the deployment of plugins, which need additional configuration, you have the possibility to pass configuration values to the plugin constructor. You should pass the configuration and configure log4net at runtime. See [how to write the plugin constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx#bkmk_writeconstructor).

Another option is to use the webressources of Dynamics CRM 2011. See [this blog article](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2011/09/adding-configuration-to-plugins-in-crm.html) which describes all available options.